# Creating an angled header in bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to create the following making use of the bootstrap nav-bar:

[image: Bootstrap angled nav-bar]

But I am having a little trouble with it - specifically the skewing at the end of the red bar. The problem is that ideally I want the title "Apps Account" in a bootstrap `container` so that it is indented to the middle of page, but then my coloured header doesn't play well as it's not starting from the side of the screen.

How can I go about making this header?

I've tried the following as a start:

CSS :

```
.row {
    position: relative;
    height:50px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.col-4 {
    background-color: #df1010;
}

.col-4 h2 {
    text-align:right;
}

.col-1 {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #df1010;
    transform: skewY(-45deg);
    transform-origin: top left;
}
```

HTML :

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-4"><h2>Apps Account</h2></div>
    <div class="col-1"></div>
</div>
```

But this has two main issues:

1. The `height` has to be set on the parent div, otherwise the skewing doesn't show at all. Ideally it'd be based on the content.
2. It doesn't scale very well when going down to mobile size, the skew doesn't go from corner to corner.

Comment: please share what you have tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Avoid styling bootstrap classes so ambiguously, you'll likely run into issues later down the line when you attempt to re-use them.

There are a number of ways to get what you're looking for, my take is as follows:

- Use the `h2` element to create a pseudo element that sits behind it, skewed, filled and stretched to act as the red background.
- Wrap the whole thing in an element that hides any overflow, to prevent your pseudo element breaking out of the main page body:

```css
#top{
  overflow: hidden;
}

#top h2{
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  position: relative;
  padding: .8rem 0;
}

#top h2::before{
  background-color: #df1010;
  bottom: 0;
  content: ' ';
  left: -9999rem;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  transform-origin: 100% 0;
  transform: skew(-40deg);
  top: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div id="top">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
        <h2>
          Apps Account
        </h2>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I've modified the bootstrap column classes in order to prevent the title wrapping on different devices, but you can of course change these to fit your needs.

Comment: Initially the CSS was posted inline between style tags, I edited it so that it would be clearer. I personnally think using a pseudo element just for the angle or a border shape as suggested by @Patrick is a better classic solution however yours addresses well the bootstrap container problem

Answer (score 2):

Just use `:before` method to add the red background angle shape. Optionally adjust the `width:40%` based on your requirement.

```css
.angle-bg {
    position: relative;
    height: 50px;    
}
.angle-bg:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 50%;
    background: #df1010;
    transform: skew(-30deg);
}
.case-item-header {
    margin: 12px 8px 14px;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="row angle-bg">
  <div class="col-6">
    <h3 class="case-item-header">Apps Account</h3>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I was about to suggest something similar, except I would keep the `background-color` and `width` on the container itself and do the skewing with a pseudo element with a white background (or whichever color the background color would be). Just like in this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3L7tmbxk/)

Answer (score 1):

I made a solution that uses default bootstrap classes. If you want a container that stretches over the whole page bootstrap provides the `.container-fluid` CSS class.

The use of the `col-xs-*` and `col-sm-*` comes with responsiveness in mind. You can simply adjust the percentages of the rows for the different screen sizes.

For the corner no usage of transformations is required. You can achieve simple shapes like this with borders to get the desired look. A piece worth reading on that subject is [The Shapes of CSS](https://css-tricks.com/the-shapes-of-css/). The steepness of the corner can be changed by manipulating the size of `border-right`.

```css
.nopadding {
  /* override bootstrap column padding*/
   padding: 0 !important;
   margin: 0 !important;
}

.title {
  height: 50px;
  color: white;
  background-color: #df1010;
}

.title h2 {
  /* override bootstrap header classes*/
  line-height: 1em;
  margin: 10px 0;
}

.corner {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 50px solid #df1010;
  border-right: 50px solid transparent;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-6 text-right title nopadding">
      <h2>Apps Account</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-6 nopadding">
      <div class="corner"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Unfortunately this does not get rid of the height definition on the parent. But it solves your screen size issues.

Comment: great solution as well ! You can safely remove `height: 50px` from `.title` though ;)

Comment: That is a coincidence. If I do that and the font-size changes the title container changes it's size and is not flush with the corner anymore.